# ¿Por qué las dos partes en las que se divide la Edad Media fueron denominadas Alta (la primera) y Baja (la segunda) en español?

Tags: terminología

Resulta confuso y contraintuitivo denominar **Alta** Edad Media a un período que antecede a otro denominado **Baja** Edad Media.

¿Existe alguna razón detrás de estos nombres?

Para mayor confusión, en inglés se divide a la Edad Media en tres períodos, siendo la Alta Edad Media la etapa del medio:

- *Early Middle Ages* (Temprana Edad Media)
- *High Middle Ages* (Alta Edad Media)
- *Late Middle Ages* (Tardía Edad Media)

Me pregunto por qué simplemente no utilizamos los terminos "temprana" y "tardía".

Comment: ¡Muy interesante pregunta! Creo que a nuestro análisis etimológico se le podría complementar el que podrían dar en [history.se] en su visión histórica, sobre todo de por qué eligieron dicho nombre.

Comment: Pensé en un principio preguntarlo en History pero no lo hice debido a que en ese sitio parece que se utiliza solo el inglés y esta denominación confusa no existe en inglés.

Comment: En [italiano](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alto_Medioevo) y en [francés](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haut_Moyen_%C3%82ge) también se habla de la Edad media como "alta" y "baja", y en [alemán](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hochmittelalter) se usa aún "alta Edad media", aunque parece que no "baja".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bueno, resulta que, como me señalaron [en esta pregunta](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/35092/why-some-languages-uses-the-term-high-to-refer-to-an-early-period-and-the-worl/35094#35094) que hice en [history.stackexchange.com](https://history.stackexchange.com/), la respuesta estuvo todo este tiempo en [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edad_Media#Baja_Edad_Media_.28siglos_XI_al_XV.29) (no se como se me pasó):

> La Baja Edad Media es un término que a veces produce confusión, pues
>   procede de un equívoco etimológico entre alemán y castellano: baja no
>   significa decadente, sino reciente; por oposición al alta de la Alta
>   Edad Media, que significa antigua (en alemán alt: viejo, antiguo).

De todas maneras, a continuación el artículo de Wikipedia también menciona esta idea de auge y decadencia, lo cual se me ocurre podría ser la razón por la cual este error etimológico se mantuvo:

> No obstante, es cierto que desde alguna perspectiva historiográfica
>   puede verse al conjunto del periodo medieval como el ciclo de
>   nacimiento, desarrollo, auge e inevitable caída de una civilización,
>   modelo interpretativo que inició Gibbon para el Imperio romano (donde
>   es más obvia la oposición entre Alto Imperio y Bajo Imperio) y que se
>   ha aplicado con mayor o menor fortuna a otros contextos históricos y
>   artísticos.

Este error de traducción desde el alemán, además, podría estar relacionado con el comentario que hizo @JMVanPelt:

> En italiano y en francés también se habla de la Edad media como "alta"
>   y "baja", y en alemán se usa aún "alta Edad media", aunque parece que
>   no "baja".

En la misma pregunta en [history.stackexchange.com](https://history.stackexchange.com/) se ofrece otra explicación muy interesante que tiene sentido, aunque no cita ninguna fuente:

> (...) Just common
>   sense. On Earth, because of gravity, things fall from top to bottom.
>   For instance rivers floes from a higher altitude to the lower ones.
>   Think of the two French departments of Haut-Rhin (in the south) and
>   Bas-Rhin (in the north): Rhine flows from South to North. Or upper
>   Egypt (in the South) and lower Egypt (in the North): the Nile also
>   flows from South to North.
>
> By analogy, everything that flows, is deemed to flow from higher to
>   lower places. This applies especially well to time. Since time always
>   move in one direction, from ancient periods to more recent ones, the
>   ancient periods are deemed "high", "higher", "upper", "hautes" in
>   French, the more recent ones "low", "lower", "basses" in French. It is
>   only natural, and applies universally: "le haut moyen-âge" in French,
>   "Alta edad media" in Spanish mean the first part of the middle age.
>   The "high antiquity" means the very ancient one. You may often find
>   sentences like "to find this elaborated artifact at such a high date
>   is surprising", where "high date" means, of course "ancient", etc.

Traducido:

> Es una cuestión de sentido común. En la Tierra, debido a la gravedad,
>   las cosas caen desde arriba hacia abajo. Por ejemplo, los ríos fluyen
>   desde una altitud mayor a una altitud menor. Piensa en los dos
>   departamentos franceses de Haut-Rhin (en el sur) y Bas-Rhin (en el
>   norte): El Rín fluye de sur a norte. O el Alto Egipto (en el sur) y el
>   Bajo Egipto (en el norte): el Nilo también fluye de sur a norte.
>
> Por analogía, todo lo que fluye se considera que lo hace desde lugares
>   más altos y hacia lugares más bajos. Esto se aplica especialmente bien
>   al tiempo. Debido a que el tiempo siempre se mueve en una sola
>   dirección, desde periodos antiguos a periodos más recientes, los
>   periodos antiguos se consideran "altos", "superiores" o "hautes" en
>   francés, mientras que los más recientes se consideran "bajos",
>   "inferiores" o "basses" en francés. Es natural y se aplica
>   universalmente: "le haut moyen-âge" en francés, "Alta edad media" en
>   español, se refiere a la primera parte de la edad media. La "alta
>   antigüedad" se refiere al periodo más antiguo. Con frecuencia podemos
>   encontrar frases en inglés como "to find this elaborated artifact at
>   such a high date is surprising" (*encontrar este artefacto tan
>   elaborado en una fecha tan alta es sorprendente*), donde "high date"
>   (*alta fecha*) significa, por supuesto, "antiguo", etc.

Comment: Es raro, en alemán a la alta Edad media se la llama _Hoch-_ ("alta") y no _Alt-_ ("antigua"), por lo cual no entiendo de dónde vendría la confusión.

Answer (score 6):

También a mí siempre me ha parecido curioso, pero nunca me lo había planteado.

Veo sin embargo que el DRAE le da una explicación:

> [**alto**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=27ieUu8%7C27onkvl)
>
> 11. adj. Dicho de un determinado período histórico: Que está en sus primeras etapas. El Alto Imperio.

Aunque curiosamente también puede querer decir lo contrario:

> 21. adj. Dicho de un período de tiempo: Avanzado o próximo a su fin. Bien alta la noche. A altas horas de la noche.

Realizando una búsqueda más exhaustiva me encuentro con que el [Mapa de Diccionarios](http://www.rae.es/recursos/diccionarios/diccionarios-anteriores-1726-1992/mapa-de-diccionarios) revela distintas curiosidades:

- la acepción 11 (la primera que cito) solo está presente desde la edición de 2001, si bien ya en 1992 se cita:

> adj.Con referencia a tiempos históricos, remoto o antiguo. La ALTA Edad Media, el ALTO Imperio.

Que posteriormente en 2001 se "sumerge" en la tercera acepción:

> 3. adj. Más elevado en relación a otro término inferior.

- la acepción 21 (la segunda) ya aparece en 1925.

Por tanto, la sensación que da es que en la gente que recoge las entradas para el diccionario últimamente predomina la visión de nuestro tiempo como un camino cuesta abajo en el que ahora mismo estamos en la parte baja. ¿Os convence el razonamiento? A mí no demasiado.

Sin embargo, si analizamos la evolución histórica del término *alta edad media* observamos que es un concepto relativamente nuevo, tal y como muestra [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=alta+edad+media&year_start=1200&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Calta%20edad%20media%3B%2Cc0) en el que observamos que antes de 1900 no se usaba:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Justo iba a exponer lo mismo que fedorqui acaba de responder: las palabras "[alto](http://dle.rae.es/?id=27ieUu8%7C27onkvl)" y "[bajo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4oyrC6G)" ya tienen esos significados (acepciones 11 y 17, respectivamente). Añadir simplemente que las etapas históricas en este caso tienen similitud con los imperios: tienen un auge y un declive. Imagínate las etapas históricas de la siguiente forma: como una gráfica en la que exponemos el tiempo en el eje horizontal y, digamos, el esplendor de la etapa histórica en el vertical. En el centro del periodo considerado tendremos el máximo esplendor, y en los extremos menos esplendor, quedando la gráfica como una campana de Gauss.

Por tanto, a la primera mitad de la gráfica, que se consideraría el auge hacia su máximo esplendor (es decir, el periodo al alza), se le denomina el periodo "alto", mientras que la segunda mitad, el periodo en declive o a la baja, sería el periodo "bajo".

Comment: Es interesante pues parece indicar que la visión actual va encaminada a esta forma de ver el tiempo de esta manera, pero escarbando un poco parece que no siempre fue así.

Answer (score 3):

Como ya se dijo, *alto* y *bajo* en historia refieren a "temprano" y "tardío" respectivamente. Vale aclarar, sin embargo, que **en geología y paleontología** la imagen de auge y declive es reemplazada por la referencia a la profundidad de los estratos, de lo cual resulta que se utiliza el término *superior* para denominar a las épocas más recientes ("Cretácico Superior") e *inferior* para los más antiguos. La razón es que las capas de sedimentos donde se encuentran los fósiles, por ejemplo, se encuentran generalmente más abajo cuanto más antiguas sean, por obvias razones.

En inglés se utilizan alternativamente las dos terminologías (se dice *Upper Cretaceous* o *Late Cretaceous*, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

[La respuesta aceptada](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/19458/1674) no incluye una fuente de su argumento. También asume una traducción del alemán que no parece ser acertada (*alt*). Para complementar las respuestas existentes, ajunto lo que aparece en el libro "La Edad Media a debate", de L. K. Little (2003).

[image]
[image]

También vale la pena notar que a veces se usa "temprana edad media" y "edad media tardía", como demuestra Google Ngram. Sin embargo, el uso de estos es mucho menos frecuente que el de alta y baja edad media.

Comment: Sería interesante que proporcionaras versión en texto de la imagen que añades, para facilitar la lectura y búsqueda